# Assign multiple keys a certain value using ramda.js assocPath?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ramda.js

I am quite new to JS and ramda.js. Let's say i have an object consisting of empty objects like this:

```
obj = { 1: { }, 2: { }, 3: { } }
```

and array consisting of chosen keys of the `obj` .

```
arr = ['1', '2']
```

What i need is to create a certain key-value pair, for example `a: 'value'`, inside of the key objects chosen via `arr`, so the result would look like this:

```
obj = { 
 1: { a: 'value' }, 
 2: { }, 
 3: { a: 'value' } 
}
```

I have tried to .map through the keys with

```
arr.map(key => assocPath([key, 'a'], 'value', obj) )
```

, and also tried a way with `arr.forEach()`, but it doesn't work and i believe i may be missing some basic knowledge? Or is there an alternative ramda.js function i should use?

Comment: ```arr.map(key => assocPath(obj[key], 'a'], 'value', obj) )``` this will work, does it  create the mappings you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my solution

```js
const object = { 1: { }, 2: { }, 3: { } }
const array = ['1', '3']

function magic(obj, arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key]: { a: 'value' },
  }), obj)
}

console.log(magic(object, array))
```

This is also can be achieved with ramda's functions

```js
const object = { 1: { }, 2: { }, 3: { } }
const array = ['1', '3']

const magicR = R.reduce((acc, key) => R.assocPath([ key, 'a' ], 'value', acc))

console.log(magicR(object, array))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with `.forEach()`:

```
arr.forEach(key => obj[key] = { a: 'value' });
```

The `.map()` function is for creating a new array from the elements of a source array, and you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Ramda methods are immutable - they don't mutate the original object, but return a new one. The R.assocPath method is no different in this regard. To update the object, you'll need to iterate the array with R.reduce, use R.assocPath, get a new object, etc...

```js
const { reduce, assocPath } = R

const fn = reduce((o, key) => assocPath([key, 'a'], 'value', o))

const obj = { 1: { }, 2: { }, 3: { } }
const arr = ['1', '2']

const result = fn(obj)(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```